# SciFi-HiFi Keychain problem - SecKeychainItemRef undeclared error

Tags: iphone, keychain, security-framework

I'm trying to use this class:

http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code

to save data to the keychain on the iPhone. I've included the header and the .m file in my application and included the security framework, however I'm still getting these undeclared errors.

I can't seem to find any tutorials or help file for setting up this class within a project, so I'm led to believe that it's not that difficult. Just causing me problems.

I'm running the 3.0 sdk, though I don't think that will affect things much.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: What is it saying is undeclared?  Please edit your post and add the exact error messages you're getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the full iPhone Keychain API is now available in the simulator (as of 3.0)... just make sure any #ifdefs that refer to

```
TARGET_ IPHONE_SIMULATOR
```

are disabled, and you should be fine.

Comment: This seems to work - awesome! Thanks!

Not tried it on the device yet, since code signing is a seperate issue. Grr!

Comment: Just to add to this. You actually have to be building against the 3.0 SDK not just using a copy of XCode that supports 3.0.